# How do I remove the actual decimal from a numeric field that I'm converting to text? ex: 125.02 needs to be 12502

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm creating an OCR line for our remits that our scanner will read.  The scanner doesn't allow the '.' in the field - it assumes the last 2 digits are the decimal place values.  I'm converting the field to to text but not sure how to remove the '.' and keep the decimal place values.

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution would be to create a Formula Field and use the Replace() function.  The formula for your Formula Field would look like this:

```
StringVar myVariable;

myVariable := Replace({table.column}, ".", "");
myVariable;
```

This will search {table.column} for the first occurrence of a decimal and replace it with an empty string.

However, if your intent is to barcode the value, there may be a UFL available that could also do this for you.  When creating barcodes, User Function Libraries are usually preferred because they have functions specifically designed to encode your barcode values.  They aren't required though and you can always choose to manually encode barcode values manually with Formula Fields.

Comment: Thank you! Going to try this!